# Export/import compressed WSL2 distros

Tags: powershell, wsl2

I'm looking for a way to compress WSL2 distros while exporting it, and have tried to pass the tar file produced by `wsl` to `7z` through pipe, but after about an hour, it produced nothing but CPU load and the `7z` process wasn't even started according to Task Manager:

```
wsl --export myDistro - | 7z a -tgzip myDistro.tar.gz -si
```

- I tried to pass a sample tar file though pipe to `7z` and `sample.tar.gz` was created without any issue:

  ```
  Get-Content -Path sample.tar -Raw | 7z a -tgzip sample.tar.gz -si
  ```
- I also tried to export the distro to file instead of stdout, which took about 15 minutes and the distro was exported successfully:

  ```
  wsl --export myDistro .\myDistro.tar
  ```

What am I doing wrong? How to compress an exported WSL2 distro to a gzip archive without storing the tar file on a disk, and how to import it through pipe with `wsl --import` after that?

---

As @DanielB noticed, PowerShell doesn't transfer data through pipe as-is *(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502) and [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908))*, but what about named pipes?

- I've tried to create one, but it looks like `wsl` can't handle named pipes:

  ```
  $ New-Object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("\\.\pipe\wsl-exp-imp"); wsl --export experimentinGentoo '\\.\pipe\wsl-exp-imp'

      The system cannot find the file specified.
  ```

In Windows, is there a way to create a file-like named pipe as `mkfifo` does in Linux?

Answer (score 5):

What you want works perfectly fine. In Command Prompt.

Pipes in PowerShell are not sane when non-Cmdlets are involved. Do not use them. If you want to script in PowerShell, use `cmd /c "whatever"` to escape to Command Prompt for a single command.

Comment: Looks so. Here's an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502) of how PowerShell processes data while transferring it through pipe. And here's a related [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908) that's been open for 5 years. I'm a newbie in PowerShell and kind of surprised that it doesn't provide such basic functionality as transferring data through pipe as-is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a an example of exporting a WSL distro
with an on-the-fly compression.

It is slower (10G/12min w compression vs 10G/8min w/o compression),
but the compressed size is about the 1/10 of the source size.

```
wsl --export --vhd Ubuntu-18.04 - | "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -si -so -tgzip -an -bsp2 > \\\192.168.1.13\d\wsl\Ubuntu-18.04.vhdx.gz
```